# Radial gradient for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am trying to do an animation with pure css3. The animation would be eyes that move left to right, my probleme is I using radial gradient background for the eyes but on Internet Explorer this effect doesn't look to work, but on Chrome and Firefox its working well.

You can see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/h6VYd/

here the css code :

```
body {

}

.ball {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 40%, 0, 50% 40%, 100, color-stop(0%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(66%, #efeff1), color-stop(100%, #9b5050));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 40%, circle cover, #fcfcfc, #efeff1 66%, #9b5050 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 40%, circle cover, #fcfcfc, #efeff1 66%, #9b5050 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 40%, circle cover, #fcfcfc, #efeff1 66%, #9b5050 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(50% 40%, circle cover, #fcfcfc, #efeff1 66%, #9b5050 100%);
}
.ball:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 24, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), color-stop(14%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), color-stop(24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 14%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 14%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 14%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 14%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -o-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
}

.iris {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 100, color-stop(0%, #208ab4), color-stop(30%, #6fbfff), color-stop(100%, #4381b2));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, #208ab4 0%, #6fbfff 30%, #4381b2 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, #208ab4 0%, #6fbfff 30%, #4381b2 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, #208ab4 0%, #6fbfff 30%, #4381b2 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, #208ab4 0%, #6fbfff 30%, #4381b2 100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(68px) translateY(-60px) skewX(15deg) skewY(2deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(68px) translateY(-60px) skewX(15deg) skewY(2deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(68px) translateY(-60px) skewX(15deg) skewY(2deg);
  -o-transform: translateX(68px) translateY(-60px) skewX(15deg) skewY(2deg);
  transform: translateX(68px) translateY(-60px) skewX(15deg) skewY(2deg);
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: move-eye-skew 5s ease-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: move-eye-skew 5s ease-out infinite;
  -o-animation: move-eye-skew 5s ease-out infinite;
  -ms-animation: move-eye-skew 5s ease-out infinite;
  animation: move-eye-skew 5s ease-out infinite;
}
.iris:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 37.5%;
  height: 37.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 31.25%;
  left: 31.25%;
  background: black;
}
.iris:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 31.25%;
  height: 31.25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 18.75%;
  left: 18.75%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}


.stage {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@-moz-keyframes move-eye-skew {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  20% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-10px) ;
    transform: translateX(-10px); }

  25%, 44% {
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  50%, 60% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(10px) ;
    transform: translateX(10px); }

  66%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none; } }

@-webkit-keyframes move-eye-skew {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px) ;
    transform: translateX(-10px) ;}

  25%, 44% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  50%, 60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px) ;
    transform: translateX(10px); }

  66%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none; } }

@-o-keyframes move-eye-skew {
  0% {
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  20% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-10px) ;
    transform: translateX(-10px); }

  25%, 44% {
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  50%, 60% {
    -o-transform: translateX(10px);
    transform: translateX(10px); }

  66%, 100% {
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none; } }

@-ms-keyframes move-eye-skew {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  20% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
    transform: translateX(-10px); }

  25%, 44% {
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  50%, 60% {
    -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
    transform: translateX(10px); }

  66%, 100% {
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none; } }

@keyframes move-eye-skew {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-10px);
    transform: translateX(-10px); }

  25%, 44% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none; }

  50%, 60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
    -o-transform: translateX(10px);
    transform: translateX(10px); }

  66%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none; } }
```

Comment: What IE version are you testing with? (CSS gradients were only introduced in IE10, so earlier versions won't work)

Comment: I am using the version 10.0.9200.16686 of IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `-ms-radial-gradient` CSS declarations.

For example:

```
background: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 40%, circle cover, #fcfcfc, #efeff1 66%, #9b5050 100%);
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/5XCTk/).

Comment: ([ [ <shape> || <size> ] [ at <position> ] ? , | at <position> , ] ? <color-stop> [ , <color-stop> ] +)

Comment: This does not work on IE 11. Could you please update the answer to include IE 11?